# azure Cli - Making multiple subscription as default

Tags: azure

I am working to find the list of all the storage account in our Azure subscription. Unfortunately, we have around 40 subscriptions, is there a way to get all the storage account. Currently I can only see the list in one subscription & need to change the subscription to another for finding the storage account.

The following command gives me the storage account for default subscription:
`az storage account list --output table`

Comment: did you have chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the [`graph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-azurecli#add-the-resource-graph-extension) extension:
`az extension add --name resource-graph`

And then try out the following:

```sh
az graph query -q                                         \
"Resources                                                \
| join kind=leftouter                                     \
    (                                                     \
        ResourceContainers                                \
        | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' \
        | project SubName=name, subscriptionId            \
    ) on subscriptionId                                   \
| where type == 'microsoft.storage/storageaccounts'       \
| project type, name, SubName"
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers) I found the resources types.
I changed the casing to make it work.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#join) documentation gave me the hints to make the query work.